# Customize RSS Feed from Wordpress to Mailchimp

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, mailchimp

I want to edit the line of code "[…]" found in my feed drtaylorwallace.com/feed which I use to push to Mailchimp RSS feed campaigns.

The reason I want to edit this is because in Mailchimp it appears as "[...]" in the email blast which looks like it should be able to click on it to read more of the blog post on the site.

I want to: Remove the brackets (OR) enable it to be hyperlinked to that specific blog post.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilizing the wordpress excerpt field within your wp admin "edit post" view! When you use this, your feed will automatically pull that excerpt and there will be no [...]! Hope this helps!